# Does mongoose webserver require external libraries to implement SSL HTTPS?

Tags: c, ssl, https, mongoose-web-server

My application uses the mongoose embedded webserver. I have sucessfully built an HTTP server and serve files, but now I want to implement HTTPS.

Based on the mongoose documentation, this can be done by enabling **MG_ENABLE_SSL** flag and attaching self signed certificates which I already have. But after examining deeper the mongoose source code, I noticed the **MG_SSL_IF** flag which have 3 choices: OpenSSL, mBedTLS, and DirectLink.

Now for my question. Does mongoose embedded webserver requires one of the mentioned libraries above to implement HTTPS? Their documentation says it has a built in SSL/TLS:

[image]

If not, then please enlighten me on how to implement HTTPS without using any external libraries. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

External libraries are necessary. Currently Mongoose support mBedTLS or OpenSSL.
See Makefile for an example, which build flags you need to set:

```
ifeq "$(SSL)" "MBEDTLS"
MBEDTLS_DIR ?= $(shell brew --cellar mbedtls)
MBEDTLS_VER ?= $(shell brew info mbedtls --json | jq -j .[0].installed[0].version)
MBEDTLS ?= $(MBEDTLS_DIR)/$(MBEDTLS_VER)
CFLAGS += -DMG_ENABLE_MBEDTLS=1 -I$(MBEDTLS)/include -I/usr/include
LDFLAGS ?= -L$(MBEDTLS)/lib -lmbedtls -lmbedcrypto -lmbedx509
endif
ifeq "$(SSL)" "OPENSSL"
OPENSSL_DIR ?= $(shell brew --cellar openssl)
OPENSSL_VER ?= $(shell brew info openssl --json | jq -j .[0].installed[0].version)
OPENSSL ?= $(OPENSSL_DIR)/$(OPENSSL_VER)
CFLAGS += -DMG_ENABLE_OPENSSL=1 -I$(OPENSSL)/include
LDFLAGS ?= -L$(OPENSSL)/lib -lssl -lcrypto
endif
```